# Eclipse CDT Console output not showing up in debug with path and not showing up in run without path

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, console, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to get Eclipse CDT (64 bit eclipse) working on Windows 7 with GCC. When I first got GDB working (that was a challenge in itself), running the program in debug mode was the only way I got output. Running it normally didn't give any console output. After hours of googling, I figured out that if I added C:/cygwin/bin to my environment path in eclipse, I could get output when running the program normally. Then I ran it in debug mode and there was no output. I tested this a couple of times to make sure it was the addition of the path causing the problem. This is the program I was running,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So how can I get both normal and debug modes working, and why did I have to include that path in the first place (it's already in my cygwin path and why does CDT need it?) ? Also, why is it that if I add a path to my Run configurations it will also be added to my Debug configurations?

Comment: When you say "running the program in debug mode" what do you mean?  What action within Eclipse do you take to achieve this?  Can you step through the code in the debug perspective, or does the program just run and output to the console?

Comment: By debug mode I mean I hit F11 (equivalent to clicking the bug icon in the toolbar), and by normally running it I mean hitting Ctrl+F11 (equivalent to clicking the green play button in the tool bar).

Comment: But do you actually get to step through the program?

Comment: Yes, if I haven't added the Cygwin path to my run configurations and the debug output is displayed, I can step through the program. When I add the path and I can only see normal run output and not debug output, I clearly can't step through the program. But again, adding the cygwin path the Windows path as opposed to the run configuration fixes all the problems.

Comment: Hmmm.  Oh well, if your problem is fixed then that's great.  I just can't, for the life of me, understand what might cause the behaviour you describe. Adding the path to the run configuration should, effectively, just append it to your Windows path.  Perhaps it's a bug and your next update or install will fix it.  Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think I can answer everything but I use exactly the same set-up as you and I've had to deal with quite a few issues like this (I'm wondering if you had trouble how to juggle using the 32-bit/64-bit JVM and Internet browsing)!

The cygwin/bin path must be specified because that is where gcc, gdb and all the other cygwin tools and dlls are located (I'll assume you're using cygwin flavour of gcc rather than MinGW flavour).  I believe you must specify it in the Windows environment (using a win32 file path) because Eclipse is running using the Windows JVM and therefore deals with win32 paths.  Consequently, it doesn't matter that `cygwin/bin` is added to the `PATH` variable in the cygwin environment. CDT is looking for cygwin  using Eclipse, and Eclipse needs to find cygwin1.dll from Windows.

I might be totally wrong, but if I had to guess I would say that you need to make absolutely sure you have properly set the `PATH` environment variable correctly for both configurations.

One thing to note is that in Eclipse there is **no difference** between a configuration shown in the *Debug Configurations* window and one with the same name in the *Run Configurations* window.  The only difference between the two windows is that one will run the program without using a debugger and has tabs for setting debug settings.  Therefore it's no surprise that changing settings in one will also affect the other.

As you may know, for many projects the build system is set up to produce two (sometimes more) sets of binaries: one with debugging info/symbols (DEBUG) and one without (RELEASE).  In this case, you normally have two configurations in Eclipse: one to run the DEBUG binary and one to run the RELEASE binary.  Both of these will show up in both the *Debug Configurations* window and in the *Run Configurations* window.  The point is that you can run DEBUG either with or without gdb, but RELEASE cannot be used by gdb.

That said, I'm not sure why adding the correct path to the run configuration would stop the DEBUG binary from outputting to the console.  I suspect something else is going on here, perhaps a mismatch of debug info and debugger.

To (hopefully) answer your question as to how to get both configurations working, go the whole-hog and just add `C:\cygwin\bin;` to the Windows `PATH` environment variable.  I'm guessing that will allow both to work.  I'll assume you know how to do that but please post a comment if not.

The other thing to try would be to compile and run the program from a cygwin shell.  If it works there it's probably a safe bet that your `PATH` environment variable is not set correctly when using eclipse.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Edited since Eclipse must find cygwin1.dll to run programs compiled with cygwin gcc.

Comment: First of all your solution of simply adding the C:\cygwin\bin path to the Windows path worked. Secondly, eclipse continues to confuse me. I was adding it to the run/debug configurations but adding it to one was actually adding it to both. I looked in my project preferences and there was a PATH variable defined there that already had the cygwin path... So in short, while nothing in eclipse makes sense, your solution worked.

Comment: The two paragraphs about setting the project `PATH` variable were actually irrelevant.  I realise now that the path set on the *C/C++ build->Environment* page isn't relevant to this problem, as (somewhat obviously) that path is used during compilation/build-time only.  As long as your program builds properly, changing that setting shouldn't affect execution.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Glad I could be of some help! If setting the cygwin/bin path in the Windows path worked, then the problem was obviously pointing Eclipse to the correct location. However, You should be able to replicate this result using Eclipse without altering the windows path.  I've revised my answer to hopefully shed some more light on what might be going on.

Comment: In the "For what it's worth" category, Eclipse maintains its own set of environment variables in the Run/Debug configurations. While this is "helpful" by isolating the eclipse environment variables from your native environment variables (i.e. prevent botching crucial native env. vars), it was not helpful (or intuitive) in getting stdout printed to the eclipse console. A good recommendation for the eclipse maintainers would be to add a checkbox to the run configurations to have Eclipse automatically import the native environment variables.

Answer (score 8):

From [wiki eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ):
In Eclipse CDT on Windows, standard output of the program being run or debugged is fully buffered, because it is not connected to a Windows console, but to a pipe. See *bug 173732* for more details. Either add flush calls after every printf or add the following lines at the start of the main function:

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding the Path was correct before gdb 7.3. Now when I add the path I can no longer use breakpoints as it cannot find the dll files as they are no longer part of the path. To fix this you can easily add the entire path from the environment by following these instructions.

```
left click the project
enter the RUN/DEBUG settings for the project
select the executable
click edit
select Environment Tab
click Select...
scroll down to Path (Case sensitive)
check mark Path
press OK
press OK
press OK
```

You can see the dll problem as it appears in the gdb console 
  error,msg="During startup program exited with code 0xc00000be."
or
  error,msg="During startup program exited with code 0x00000135."
and you may get an error window pop up saying it could not clear the breakpoint

Comment: Seems `Path` case matters where I updated the environment path as `c:\cygwin\bin;${env_var:Path}`

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up linker
I am using MinGW.

Follow below steps.

```
Goto Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings (Tab) > MinGW C++ Linker (Option) > Add Command (g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++)   (default command is only g++)
```

Comment: Thanks dude! I use to search this solution once a year!

Answer (score 0):

Don't debug or run C or C++ applications from inside Eclipse if they target Cygwin. TK link to "you're gonna have a bad time" meme.

There are problems with Cygwin stdout/stderr that don't show up if you run the programs from the normal Cygwin console (where you would be running bash), but they do show up in pretty much every other way you can run them.

The normal way that programs run other programs in Linux and other posix-supporting environments is to reroute the i/o to a pty. Cygwin can't support pty's 100% in Windows.

Some of the problems can be ameliorated by the setvbuf calls in @infoartenovo's answer.

A flip side of this problem is that applications written to use Windows' Console API don't work well in ptys.

We are all collateral damage in an unwinnable war.

http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2011-12/msg00236.html
https://code.google.com/p/mintty/issues/detail?id=56