# Eclipse CDT output does not show in RUN mode only

Tags: console, jvm, eclipse-cdt

CDT 8.4
Eclipse Luna 4.4
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
MinGW

The Environment variables are set correctly.
The project compiles without error.
Release and Debug executeables execute via the windows console.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

When running the "Debug Configuration" in the eclipse IDE i get the expected output:

[image: expected output]

When running the "Run Configuration" in the eclipse i get an unexpected output:

[image: unexpected output]

There is no difference in the two configurations, they are the same configuration run in different modes.
Everything is a fresh installation.

What am i missing, how can i get the "Run Configuration" to display the output correctly?

I found another answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528523/eclipse-cdt-console-output-not-showing-up-in-debug-with-path-and-not-showing-up?rq=1). I feel like this problem is simmilar with the difference that. My paths are correct and i can run the programs outside of eclipse just fine. I will try to apply all the solutions but i think the answer here will be something different.

---

EDIT: 
I added JVM to the tags.
The solution may have to do with restarting the JVM. 
Does the JVM cache the environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

I got back to my computer this morning without having changed anything and the output started working.
My guess is that a restart is required after you add something to the path variable.
This is a bit weird in the modern age - but restarting did the trick.

This would also explain the reports that reinstalling helps, since people tend to restart after reinstalling something like the jvm.