# [C++]Eclipse ignores console input during debugging

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb

During debugging Eclipse doesn't "see" INPUT from built-in console, just ignores it. Simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 int a;
 cin >> a;
 cout << a << endl;
 cin >> a;
 cout << a << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

works perfectly fine when just run, but when I try to debug it, first "data on input"(?) is always a number around 40, and only zeros next, no matter what i will write to console.
So program executes, first variable is set to ~40 and all next to zeros.
Output works fine, values are written to console, only input doesn't work.

I work on Windows 10 and use MinGW.

Thanks in advance.

@EDIT
Everything works, when I use native Windows console
(.gdbinit file with `set new-console on` line)

Comment: Forgot to write about it, edited post already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse CDT Console output not showing up in debug with path and not showing up in run without path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528523/eclipse-cdt-console-output-not-showing-up-in-debug-with-path-and-not-showing-up)

Comment: It's not duplicate. I've got problem with input only, output is fine. Debugger "skips" input lines, first data in stream is always number around 40, the next ones only zeros. So code executes and produces output.

Comment: Unable to reproduce with Eclipse Neon (4.6.0), CDT 9.0.0, Mingw-w64 GCC 6.1.0.

Comment: Eclipse might be sending something to the stdin in debug mode. Add a std::getline call in your program to read it all in, and then output it to console. Maybe you will see something that will help you figure out what is going on.